# Pyspark read delta/upsert dataset from csv files

Tags: csv, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataset that is updated periodically, that I receive as a series of CSV files giving the changes. I'd like a Dataframe that contains only the latest version of each row. Is there a way to load the whole dataset in Spark/pyspark that allows for parallelism?

Example:

- File 1 (Key, Value)

  `1,ABC
  2,DEF
  3,GHI`
- File 2 (Key, Value)

  `2,XYZ
  4,UVW`
- File 3 (Key, Value)

  `3,JKL
  4,MNO`

Should result in:

`1,ABC
2,XYZ
3,JKL
4,MNO`

I know I could do this by loading each file sequentially and then using an anti join (to kick out old values being replaced) and a union, but that doesn't let the workload be parallel.

Comment: For more parallelism You could always do a `repartition` https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#transformations

Comment: The problem is that I have to read each file sequentially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import * 
alls = spark.read.csv("files/*").withColumn('filename', input_file_name())
```

Which will load all the files in the directory and allow you to operate on column with filename.

I assume that filename has some sort of timestamp or key on which You can differentiate and order them with window and row_number function.

Answer (score 4):

Amplifying on @pandaromeo's answer, this seems to work...

```
from pyspark.sql import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import row_number, desc, input_file_name


# load files, marking each with input file name
df = spark.read.csv(files).withColumn("_ifn", input_file_name())

# use a window function to order the rows for each ID by file name (most recent first)
w = Window.partitionBy(primaryKey).orderBy(desc('_ifn'))
df = df.withColumn("_rn", row_number().over(w))

# grab only the rows that were first (most recent) in each window
# clean up working columns
df = df.where(df._rn == 1).drop("_rn").drop("_ifn")
```